# Cascade Update with Autogenerated Update Stored Procedure from ADO.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I'm running MS SQL Server 2005 with .NET 2.0. My current application is written in C#.

In MSSQL I have created 2 test tables to illustrate my question:

Table 1 is setup as:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
 [n] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 [t] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [n] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

Table 2 is setup as:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T2](
 [n] [bigint] NULL,
 [Test] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
 [Num] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_T2_T1] FOREIGN KEY([n])
REFERENCES [dbo].[T1] ([n])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_T2_T1]
```

I've populated each with multiple rows.

So in short Table 1 (T1) has a bigint primary key field "n" that's mapped to the child table T2's n field. Cascade Update is set so when T1.n is modified then T2.n is updated also. If I do a simple query and I set the value of T1.n in one of the rows, I can watch the Cascade occur in the Execution Plan. If I set the value of T1.t, the cascade does not occur in the Execution Plan as expected.

In ADO.NET I've added a DataAdapter to my form and had it autogenerate the 4 stored procedures, Update appears as follows for T1: (I added some spacing to help with readability)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T1_Update]
(
 @n bigint,
 @t varchar(10),
 @Original_n bigint,
 @Original_t varchar(10)
)
AS
 SET NOCOUNT OFF;
UPDATE [T1] 
SET 
[n] = @n, 
[t] = @t 
WHERE (
([n] = @Original_n) AND 
([t] = @Original_t));

SELECT n, t FROM T1 WHERE (n = @n)
```

I can execute this stored procedure with:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @n bigint
DECLARE @t varchar(10)
DECLARE @Original_n bigint
DECLARE @Original_t varchar(10)

EXECUTE @RC = [T1_Update] 
   5, '5', 5, '4' -- n, t, Original_n, Original_t
```

In this the value of n is unchanged and the value of t changes. I would expect to see the same behavior/execution plan as if i just did "UPDATE T1 SET t='4' where n=5 and t='5'". Running this query the Execution Plan is very simple where it goes a CI Seek, Compute Scalar, CI Update, Update.

However, Running the Execute above, the Execution plan shows it scanning table T2 and performing an update on said table even though the value wasn't changed.

I assume this is due to the lines:

```
UPDATE [T1] 
SET 
[n] = @n,
```

Commenting out the [n] = @n from the T1_Update stored procedure, even though the value doesn't change, stops the Cascade Update from firing.

So assuming I want to keep the Cascade Update, is there a way to rewrite/modify the T1_Update stored procedure that was autogenerated so that the Cascade Update is only activated when the value of "n" changes and not activated when the value is unchanged?

EDIT: I removed a Foreign Key relationship on T1 that was referencing itself that was added accidentally when I was setting up this test.

Answer (score 0):

I respectfully submit that if you're updating your primary key field, it's not a primary key.  For a column to be a primary key the following three statements must be true:

1. It must never be NULL.
2. It must be UNIQUE.
3. It must never change.

The first two are commonly enforced by the database server, but most do not enforce the third one, and it's the third one that appears to be violated in your design.  In my experience, this is something that you really don't want to do.  Just because the database will allow you to do it does not mean it's a good idea.  Here there be dragons.

OK, you've been warned.  As far as HOW to do what you're trying to do - I suggest that you scrap the ON UPDATE CASCADE option on the foreign key constraint and instead create an ON UPDATE trigger on the parent table.  If you set it to fire after the update both the OLD and NEW values will be available and your code can test to see precisely which fields changed and take appropriate action.  You may also need to set the foreign key to fire on COMMIT instead of a verb time - otherwise the short period of time that the constraint will be violated will cause the update to fail off, even though it would be corrected by the time a COMMIT was issued.  (I'm not as familiar with SQL Server as I am with other databases (e.g. Oracle) and I'm not 100% positive you can defer constraint execution until COMMIT time under SQL Server.  You may need to do a little digging).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Understood and we're currently in the process of re-evaluating all the Cascade updates that were designed into the database previously to remove them. Originally it was thought that the cascade update wouldn't hurt things if the key was really unchanging, the cascade would just not fire. However what we found was that the Update procedure that was autogenerated was called, it was "changing" this value even if the value was unchanged. So I was trying to figure out why this cascade was occurring in the first place, and how to avoid it. Still confused on the why it's cascading.

Comment: @Equixor: just noticed something - why is there a foreign key on T1.n which refers to T1.n?  That is, the field refers to itself?  ???  I've just never seen this done before.

Comment: When I was adding references to test I must have added a relationship on T1 and hit Close. After pressing Add it doesn't delete it automatically if it's not modified and the default is a reference to itself (which is useless). I've deleted this reference since it's obviously not needed and the cascade behavior is not effected.